# How can I convert each alternate character of a string lowercase to uppercase and string uppercase to lowercase in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMJUL.png)

How can I convert each alternate character of a string lowercase to uppercase and string uppercase to lowercase in Jquery?
[image]

Comment: please post your code here, so that we can check the issue. Also, describe what problem you are facing.

Comment: `each alternate character of a string lowercase to uppercase and string uppercase to lowercase` what? an example of input and expected output will help

Comment: **We are not code writing service**.. Please post your code here.. then we will help you.. or First try to google it

Comment: Please share your code here in text format .. not in image

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#opt3_1").keyup(function() {
    
    var U = $("#display3_1").val($("#opt3_1").val().toLowerCase());
 
 });//length,toUpperCase,toLowerCase,if,else,for

});
</script>
<label>input</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="opt3_1" name="opt3_1" value="" /><br><br>
<label>Display</label>
<input disabled type="text" class="form-control" id="display3_1" name="display3_1" >

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the character of the string is uppercase by comparing the `ASCII` code. If it's between `65 & 90`, the character is in uppercase. 
Then by applying `toUpperCase` & `toLowerCase` methods will transform uppercase alphabets into lowercase and vice-versa.

```js
function isUpperCase(c) {
  return c >= 65 && c <= 90;
}
var string = "AaBbCcDd *+-";
var updatedString = string.split("").map(c => isUpperCase(c.charCodeAt(0)) ? c.toLowerCase() : c.toUpperCase()).join("");

console.log("Original String:: " + string);
console.log("Transformed String:: " + updatedString);
```

Comment: Very Well Mr. @Anurag

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code alternate character

```js
function alternate(changeString) {
    var charArray = changeString.toLowerCase().split("");
    for (var i = 1; i < charArray.length; i += 2) {
        charArray[i] = charArray[i].toUpperCase();
    }
    return charArray.join("");
};

var text = "Test";
console.log(alternate(text));
```

Comment: or simply `.replace(/(.)(.)/g, (_,l,u) => l.toLowerCase() + u.toUpperCase())` ... always wanted an excuse to post `(.)(.)` :p

Comment: of course .. non alpha characters will mess up the order - possibly :p

Answer (score 0):

For the transformation, you can use the following:

```
function isLowerCase(character) {
  return "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".indexOf(character) >= 0;
}

function convertChar(character) {
  return isLowerCase(character) ? character.toUpperCase() : character.toLowerCase();
}

function convert(str) {
  var result = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    result += convertChar(str[i]);
  }
}
```

A complete example here: (although it isn't exact the same that is in your pic)

```js
function isLowerCase(character) {
  return "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".indexOf(character) >= 0;
}

function convertChar(character) {
  return isLowerCase(character) ? character.toUpperCase() : character.toLowerCase();
}

function convert(str) {
  var result = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    result += convertChar(str[i]);
  }
  return result;
}

$('#text').on('input', function(){
  $('#display').val(convert(this.value));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>input</label><input id="text" />

<label>display</label><input id="display" disabled />
```

Comment: Yes, this is the other possible interpretation of the question :p

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code may be it will help you,
Keyup event will work each character

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var upperCase= new RegExp('[A-Z]');
var lowerCase= new RegExp('[a-z]');

  $("#text").keyup(function(){  
  var l =this.value.length;
  var s =this.value;
  var r =new Array();
for(var i=0;i<l;i++){
    if(upperCase.test(s[i])){    
      r.push(s[i].toString().toLowerCase());    
    }
    if(lowerCase.test(s[i])){      
      r.push(s[i].toString().toUpperCase());   
    }
}
    $("#res").val(r.toString().replace(/\,/g, '').trim());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text">
<br>
Result:<input type="text" id="res">
```

Comment: This is not an answer of the question being asked by the OP. This answer converts each alphabet in to upper & lower case, whereas OP is asking a method to convert only upper to lower & lower to upper case.

Comment: @akuma ToT Please refer  now